# Stanford parser output to SVG

Tags: svg, stanford-nlp

I am using [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml). With provided GUI tool it outputs grafic tree from the sentence - [like this](http://screencast.com/t/3xqeJIQSxA) but when saving output it just gives bracketed format like this `(ROOT (NP (NP (DT The) (NN capability))...`.
Is it possible to get the same output(SVG) using command line?
If not, maybe there is some other tools for that? Maybe getting DOT file first and use Graphviz to get SVG in the end!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I wrote my own script to get DOT format and used it further with Graphviz to get SVG output.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

            Annotation document = new Annotation(args[0]);

            pipeline.annotate(document);

            List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

            for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
                SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
                System.out.println(dependencies.toDotFormat());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try d3.js. Here is an example of a tree: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html. Other examples are here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery. If you want to do the rendering with d3 from the command line, try it with combination with PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/). PhantomJS also allows you to print the result in PNG or SVG. This is how I'd approach it as a web guy. An advantage of this is that you'll be able to run it in a browser and maybe add some interactivity in the future. Depends on your application of course...

Comment: In this case it`s not about which graphic tool to use but how to do it automatic(semi-automatic) using Stanford Parser